# Combine two commands in bash elif (FreeNAS)

Tags: bash, if-statement, freebsd

I'm really sorry to annoy to you again with my problem but it seems I'm about to finish. My goal is to create a bash-script that checks if a IP-address is still online or a scrub is in progress and if not that my systems shuts down. My script, which is currently in use, looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=(
  10.10.0.100 #Client 1
  10.10.0.101 #Client 2 
  10.10.0.102 #Client 3 
  10.10.0.103 #Client 4
  10.10.0.104 #Client 5
)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
    echo "No Shutdown - At least one PC ($host) is online"
    exit 0
  fi
done

echo "No PC is online - Shutdown"
bash shutdown -p now
```

I did some research and found the following command, to check if my scrub is in progress

```
if [ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]; then
    echo "No Shutdown - Scrub in progess"
    exit 0
  fi
```

But i have problems in combining these two. I want my script to first check the IPs and if they all are offline then check for a scrub before it shuts down the machine. So both if-cases have to be false (ips offline and scrub not in progress) but they should be processed chronological and if the first if-case returns a IP which is online the script should stop.

Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: You'll have a lot better luck ask Unix questions on the [Unix platform](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a command output contains a string, just:

```
if zpool status | grep -q 'scrub in progress'; then
```

The `[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]` is invalid. The `$( .. )` will expand to multiple words and will run `[ scrub in progress ]`. Because `in` is not a valid operator for `[`, then `[` will print an error message and exit with `2`. Just check the error status of grep.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer is trivial:

```
hosts=(
  10.10.0.100 #Client 1
  10.10.0.101 #Client 2 
  10.10.0.102 #Client 3 
  10.10.0.103 #Client 4
  10.10.0.104 #Client 5
)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
    echo "No Shutdown - At least one PC ($host) is online"
    exit 0
  fi
done

if $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress'); then
  echo "No Shutdown - Scrub in progess"
  exit 0
fi    

echo "No PC is online and Scrub is not in progress - Shutdown"
shutdown -p now
```

Or did I miss the point?

Mind a couple of corrections inside of your code: remove the square brackets around the if test and remove the bash before shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can negate the exit status by using `!`

```
if ! ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
  if ! [[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]]; then
    echo "No PC is online - Shutdown"
    bash shutdown -p now
  fi
fi

## Add the rest of the script here if both conditions are true.
```

That basically means both condition are false, meaning there is no host up and scrub is not in progress, the opposite without the `!`

Check if both conditions are true just remove the `!`

```
if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
  if [[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]]; then
    echo "No Shutdown - At least one PC ($host) is online"
    exit 0
  fi
fi
```

Check if hosts are up but scrub is not running.

```
if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
  if ! [[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]]; then
   ##: Add/run/execute your code here to start scrub.
  fi
fi
```

If Nesting is what you want that would be something like.

```
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
    echo "No Shutdown - At least one PC ($host) is online"
    exit 0
  elif ! ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
    if ! [[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]]; then
      echo "No PC is online - Shutdown"
      bash shutdown -p now
    fi
  fi
done
```

You can add the test for zpool inside the first if-statement.

```
    for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
      if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
        if [[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]]; then
          echo "No Shutdown - At least one PC ($host) is online"
          exit 0
        fi
      fi
      elif ! ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
        if ! [[ $(zpool status | grep 'scrub in progress') ]]; then
          echo "No PC is online - Shutdown"
          bash shutdown -p now
        fi
      fi
    done
```

The first example set of if-statement should be enough though.
see `help test`